# Select inside Include in EF Core

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have an entity that looks like this (partially removed for brevity, it includes many other properties):

```
public class Tender
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string CreatorId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("CreatorId")]
    public virtual AppUser Creator { get; set; }
    public ICollection<TenderCircle> TenderCircles { get; set; } = new List<TenderCircle>();
}
```

The `TenderCircles` property is used to provide a many-to-many relationship with another entity called `Circle`. `TenderCircle` entity looks like this:

```
public class TenderCircle
{
    public int TenderId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("TenderId")]
    public Tender Tender { get; set; }
    public int CircleId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("CircleId")]
    public Circle Circle { get; set; }
}
```

Now, I'm doing the following query (partially removed for brevity, normally it includes many other `Include` and `ThenInclude` statements):

```
return _context.Tenders
               .Include(t => t.Creator)
               .Include(t => t.TenderCircles.Select(tc => new { CirlceId = tc.CircleId, TenderId = tc.TenderId }))
               .ToList();
```

But, it simply doesn't work. What I want to achieve is that I only want to get the `TenderId` and `CircleId` properties from `TenderCircle` and ignore the actual `Tender` and `Circle` objects. Any idea how to achieve this in **EF Core**?

Comment: What is the .NET Core version of your project?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Write your query as follows:

```
return _context.Tenders.Select(t => new TenderViewModel
                       {
                          Id = t.Id,
                          Creator = t.Creator,
                          TenderCircles = t.TenderCircles.Select(tc => new TenderCircle { CirlceId =  tc.CircleId, TenderId = tc.TenderId }).ToList();
                       }).ToList();
```

Then `TenderViewModel` as follows:

```
public class TenderViewModel
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public AppUser Creator { get; set; }
   public List<TenderCircle> TenderCircles { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This can get pretty cumbersome in my case, since as I have written above, there are many other `Include` and `ThenInclude` statements involved

Comment: @tinker well this solution is probably what you need. Since when you write select you dont need include, you are telling what to take from database. And please note that you do select before you do .ToList()

Comment: So you need to select the required fields that’s it